# Clean way to ensure statement execution when the previous statement fails

Tags: java, data-structures, exception

I am invoking methods in the following way:

```
operation1();
operation2();
operation3();
operation4();
operation5();
operation6();
```

I need that when a sentence fails, the following ones are executed. I plan to do it in the following way: with labels based on the type of exception thrown, each operation has an exception type.

```
    try {

        op1:operation1();
        op2:operation2();
        op3:operation3();
        op4:operation4();
        op5:operation5();
        op6:operation6();

        } catch (Operation1Exeption e) {
            break op2;
        } catch (Operation2Exeption e){
            break op3;
        } catch (Operation3Exception e){
          ...
        }
```

But it does not convince me, I would like to know if java has any better way to achieve this, or if any know some structure that could help me.

My solution is to create a class for each operation so that it would not look so dirty with so much try-catch for each line, so the sentence block looks like this:

```
Operation1.doWork();
Operation2.doWork();
Operation3.doWork();
Operation4.doWork();
```

Each operation processes its errors in the service method, so if an operation throws an exception it is processed within the service method and the next operation is executed regardless of the result of the previous one.

```
public class Operation1 {

    public void doWork() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Operation1 work done!!!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Operation 1 fail!!!");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you already thought about using the [chain of responsibility pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)? This would be a better design than using exceptions and labels.

Comment: Just FYI, using the go-to pattern (labels, directions after `break`'s), is generally frowned upon in Java except in `switch` cases. It's a remnant of a style of programming that's fallen out of favor. See e.g. [the wikipedia article on Goto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto)

Comment: The proposed solutions seemed somewhat complex, I was waiting for a simpler answer, with my little experience I expected to find some pattern or utility that would help me to make the code that manages this part not look so dirty, It seemed simple at first, I do not know how to work correctly with threads and I think I do not have the knowledge to propose a solution with them. My solution was to create a class for each operation and that each class was responsible for handling the errors. yes, It's like putting the garbage under the carpet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a list with method references, and then iterate over them and catch any exception thrown:

```
List<Runnable> methods = Arrays.asList(this::operation1, this::operation2 /* etc... */);
methods.forEach(r -> {
    try {
        r.run();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
});
```

Comment: It's simple and it works, but only if java is greater than or equal to 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct built-in solution.

A more reasonable way would be to use a class that takes a list of Callable objects for example. That class walks these objects and invokes them. You could also provide a "policy" object that defines how to react when one of the calls fails.

Hardcoding it, like in your example is a really inflexible implementation. It is fine for a prototype, but in case you have to maintain this for a real product, I suggest that you look into creating such a framework.

Where a simple solution would be to use a single threaded ExecutorService. Simply submit each invocation as task into that service.

Answer (score 0):

To Execute the next method even after an exception occurs. Each and every methods can be put in separate try catch block.